# No one answered my question for 20 days

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I have a question about my Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange post: [My ZTE Z812 is not rebooting when when I press and hold the power button](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/202274/my-zte-z812-is-not-rebooting-when-when-i-press-and-hold-the-power-button)

I have waited 20 days for an answer and I got nothing. No upvotes, no downvotes, only one comment, and 15 views, and need my question answered as soon as possible. why is no one answering my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases, not getting an answer is a sign that your question is unclear or missing some crucial information, but I read your question and I don't see anything wrong with it.

In your case it could just be a sign that your problem is not a common one and your phone is not very popular - I don't think any of our regular chat visitors have a ZTE phone. In that case it might be a while before your question is seen by someone with enough experience of this phone to have seen a similar problem.

I've added a relevant tag to help your question be found in search, but you can also help by sharing your question on any ZTE owners' forums you know of.